# Logic for my land size calculator application

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I'm making this acres and karats calculator for my uncle to help him in his work.

I'll explain the whole idea of this thing with this example. So if you add 3.22 + 2.2 it should be = 5.42 but in this calculator 3.22 + 2.2 should = 6, because 3 acres + 2 acres = 5 acres and 22 karats + 2 karats = 1 acre, so the total would be 6 acres.

The way I'm doing it in the code is that I'm splitting a number like 3.22 to two, 3 and 22 and the other number to 2 and 2 and I add the whole numbers together and the fractions together and if the fractions are >= 24 I add one to the whole numbers and if there're fractions left from the whole calculation I leave it. For example 3.15 + 2.15 = 6.6, but I'm stuck on how I can add the numbers, there's also an error in there that I don't know how to resolve.

Anyway here's the [code](https://codepen.io/person_0/pen/wvawBaY)

```
function getValue(v) {
    return +v.toString().match(/\.(\d*)/)[1] || 0;
}
function getTotal() {
    d += Math.floor(num);
    p += getValue(num);

    if (p >= 24) {
        p -= 24;
        ++d;
    }
    total = d + p / 100;
    ptag.textContent = total;
}
```

I added the part of the code where I'm stuck.

Note: I'm trying to make the thing able to add multiple numbers not only two. Also I'm trying to add subtraction but I have no idea how to start working on the subtraction because I haven't even finished the addition.

Answer (score 2):

If the error you are talking about is something like this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null
```

It is because of your getValue function.
My suggestion is, instead of using something as complicated as

```
function getValue(v) {
return +v.toString().match(/\.(\d*)/)[1] || 0;
}
```

use

```
function getValue(v) {
    return floor((v % 1) * 100);
}
```

This has the same effect as the code you wrote. Which for example, from input 3.13, returns 13.

But there are few other problems.

First, you should update your *num* variable every now and often, otherwise, it is always going to stay as an empty string (you only defined it on line 20, and you didn't update it after that).

Second, you should clear the *d* and *p* variable after you use. As of right now, both of these variables just keeps on increasing every time you run the *getTotal* function

---

For your question of how you can add two numbers, I suggest you to create a variable where you can store the first number that the user typed.

For example, when the user typed in 4.19 and pressed the plus button, save that 4.19 into a variable (let's say *firstNum*).
Then when the user pressed equal button, add the **number from the current input field**  with the *firstNum* variable.

---

On how exactly you are going to add two different numbers, break two numbers you want to add into Acres part and Karats parts. Then add them separately, then use your *getTotal*.

So if the number is 3.21 and 5.18, add 3 and 5, add 21 and 18, then add both of them.
you'll get 8.39. Finally, convert 8.39 into 9.15.

Sorry if my calculation is not correct. It is my first time with this concept!
But I believe this is the way to go.

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for your answer, I'm now updating the num variable, but there's  a problem which is that the `input.addEventListener("keypress", function() {
 num = input.value * 1; 
});` returns the value missing the last number, for example if I type 3.22 it returns as 3.2 in the num variable. I'm also trying to make the getTotal() function to work if I press the plus key on the keyboard, I made it work when I click on the plus button on the page, [updated code](https://codepen.io/person_0/pen/wvawBaY)